# How to remove headers, footers and any other extra information besides main body text, from PDF?

Tags: pdf

How to remove headers, footers and any other extra information besides main body text, from PDF file?

For example from this document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/avbsk63khasv2x4/test.pdf?dl=1

Preferably:

- for free
- in batch
- keeping the main body untouched
- in command line
- with open source software
- on Linux

Comment: Please note, unless the PDF is fully Tagged (which is rare) then PDF format has no concept of "header", "footer" or even "body". It it just graphics operators defining drawing commands. So what you are asking for, especially a general solution, is non-trivial.

Comment: What I think of now is to remove text based on its font and size - How to do that?